# Как в Unity подключить БД Access?

Tags: c#, база-данных, unity3d, access

Помогите пожалуйста подключить БД из Access в Unity
Был бы признателен, если бы написали код подключения и сказали, если нужны какие-то библиотеки
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Так же как и в любом другом .NET Framework приложении. Но вообще в Unity с базами данных не работают.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать код подключения БД? И нужно ли какие-то библиотеки подключать?

Comment: попробуйте [погуглить](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+ms+access+database&sxsrf=ALeKk00wwFgitDZVQJxU4GjOQyQ-z8tmNQ%3A1621984957153&ei=vYatYMHxCNj2sAfsqrEg&oq=unity+ms+access+database&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQkD5Y1j9ggUJoAXACeACAAXWIAZYDkgEDMi4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiBxM7p_OXwAhVYO-wKHWxVDAQQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) и возможно решение найдется.